# What is secure way to use jquery no conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i am developing wordpress plugin , plugin needs jquery , the problem is when I tried to use 
`jQuery`  keyword it works if wordpress use no conflicts, if no conflict is not added by theme builder I mean in older wordpress theme they used the keyword like `$`

**Problem :**

**1.** How to detect the jquery no conflict triggered or not ?

**2.** Or need that dom ready function which is will work for both no.Conflict `jQuery` and `$`

Thank You.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there shouldn't ever be a time where `$` refers to jQuery and `jQuery` does not, even if you're using no conflict mode. The whole point of no conflict is to handle different frameworks all trying to use the `$` shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for quick reply , i want to run wp-plugin on older wordpress theme which include jquery with older versions, just want a code that will run at any condition : with or without no conflict. it will be Great if i got some code example :)

Comment: Added an answer that covers how to get `$` to refer to the instance of jQuery regardless. The key point is that `jQuery` *always* refers to (a version of) jQuery if it has been loaded on the page. If `jQuery` is undefined then you don't have jQuery loaded at all.

Comment: Thank You Anthony Save My Time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's no conflict mode is intended to resolve disputes between multiple frameworks (or instances of jQuery) that all want to use the `$` shortcut. There shouldn't ever be a case, regardless of whether or not `jQuery.noConflict()` has been called, where `$` refers to jQuery and `jQuery` doesn't also refer to (a version of) jQuery.

If you want to use `$` to refer to jQuery, regardless of no conflict status, then you can do something like this:

```
(function($) {
    // code that uses jQuery here
})(jQuery);
```

That's an immediately invoked function expression which has a parameter named `$` which is passed the `jQuery` variable. It creates a closure inside of which you can be guaranteed that `$` refers to jQuery, it's the standard way that jQuery plugins are written if they want to be able to use the `$` shortcut.

If you're always using a DOM ready handler, and all of your code using jQuery is inside of the function passed to it, it has a similar mechanism for doing that since the DOM ready handler always passes the instance of jQuery to that function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // $ definitely refers to jQuery here
});

// $ may or may not refer to jQuery here
```